# store csv values to hashmap in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to store csv values to a hashmap. Suppose my column names are errorcode and errormessage in the csv, can any one please help me with the sample code as I am stuck with the same. I have tried to put it using java, but I am not able to read the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via [Beanshell Scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) like

**To put the values:**

```
Map map = null;    
if (bsh.shared.map == void) {
    map = new HashMap();        
}
else {
    map = bsh.shared.map;        
}
map.put(vars.get("errorcode"),vars.get("errormessage"));
bsh.shared.map = map;
```

**To read the values:**

```
Map map = bsh.shared.map;

Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        String errorcode = pair.getKey();
        String errormessage = pair.getValue();
        //do what you need to do with the values from the HashMap            
}
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter